# How to pad Pandas dataframe column with different sizes with Nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to equalize size of a list in a dataframe column which looks like this:

```
0             [2116.0, 6999.0, 2116.0, 2166.0, 2503.0]
1                             [2113.0, 6999.0, 2314.0]
2             [2111.0, 6999.0, 2111.0, 2362.0, 2503.0]
3                     [2100.0, 6999.0, 2362.0, 2113.0]
4                     [2111.0, 6999.0, 2111.0, 2503.0]
```

with something like this (Nan at the end of list):

```
0             [2116.0, 6999.0, 2116.0, 2166.0, 2503.0]
1             [2113.0, 6999.0, 2314.0, NaN,       NaN]
2             [2111.0, 6999.0, 2111.0, 2362.0, 2503.0]
3             [2100.0, 6999.0, 2362.0, 2113.0,    NaN]
4             [2111.0, 6999.0, 2111.0, 2503.0,    NaN]
```

Comment: How exactly one is supposed to know which specific columns are to be filled with `NaN`? Always the last ones?

Comment: Yes @desertnaut , in my case I want only the last ones for filled. Thanks for noting that down, I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new DataFrame to pad.  Since creating a DataFrame with these values fills in `NaN` for missing values by default, you can then aggregate to `list` across the first axis to add the necessary padding to the list.

Assuming your column name is `0`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist()).agg(list, 1)
```

```
0    [2116.0, 6999.0, 2116.0, 2166.0, 2503.0]
1          [2113.0, 6999.0, 2314.0, nan, nan]
2    [2111.0, 6999.0, 2111.0, 2362.0, 2503.0]
3       [2100.0, 6999.0, 2362.0, 2113.0, nan]
4       [2111.0, 6999.0, 2111.0, 2503.0, nan]
```

---

***However***

It is generally ill-advised to store lists in DataFrames.  Why not just expand the lists to their own columns? This will also leave the `NaN` padding:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist())
```

```
        0       1       2       3       4
0  2116.0  6999.0  2116.0  2166.0  2503.0
1  2113.0  6999.0  2314.0     NaN     NaN
2  2111.0  6999.0  2111.0  2362.0  2503.0
3  2100.0  6999.0  2362.0  2113.0     NaN
4  2111.0  6999.0  2111.0  2503.0     NaN
```